# Reading the Guzzle response with some nested JSON objects

Tags: php, json, guzzle

I have made a http request to my api using Guzzle library as follow :

```
$client = new Client();
            $response = $client->request(
                'GET',
                config('some_url');
            $serverResponse = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
            if ($serverResponse['result']) {
                $data = $serverResponse['data'];
```

Now I got the response as

```
{
    "result": true,
    "data": {
        "101": {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "ABCD",
            "age" : 24
            },
         "102": {
            "id": 102,
            "name": "EFGH",
            "age" : 24
            },
         "103": {
            "id": 103,
            "name": "IJKL",
            "age" : 24
            },
}
}
```

The problem is I need to read and push the object models 101,102,103 to a separate array. for this I try to get the objects as following options. but I could not able to get the results rather than errors.

```
$obj = $data[0];
```

It returns Undefined offset: 0 error

Comment: guzzle not gazzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your data is being manually indexed, as opposed to something like:

```
{
    "data": {
        0: {
           "id": 101,
           ...
        },
        1: {
           "id": 102,
           ...
        },
        ...
     }
}
```

You will need to specify these indexes when fetching the data. E.g:

`$data["101"]`

To do this for dynamically set data you can use `array_keys`

```
$obj = $data[array_keys($data)[0]];
```

Using `array_keys` allows you to search `$data` by the numerical index of `$data`

Comment: It's dynamic one. so I can't call that one. Only the way is able to call from the index. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to re-index the array so that the keys are `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. you can use the following:

```
$newArray = array_values($data);
```

You will then be able to access the first sub-array with `$newArray[0]`, the second with `$newArray[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the response to object and then you can access the properties as following.

```
$obj = json_decode($response->getBody());
$one_zero_one = $obj->data->{101};
```